# Less Verbose maven surefire test output

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Currently maven test produces a whole lot of logs on console and it is hard to navigate through to find failures/successes. Is there a way to reduce the output of maven surefire test similar to -q for regular install? I would be more than happy with just the final list of success and failure.

Comment: There is a clear part where all tests are reported... ? Can you please give an example what you exactly have what you like to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can achieve this by adding  `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn`